# Number of concurrent events per username in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a table like the following but approximately 7 million rows. What I am trying to find out is how many cases is each user working on simultaneously? I would like to groupby the username and then get an average count of how many references are open concurrently between the two times.

| Reference | starttime | stoptime | Username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-07-28 06:41:56.000 | 2020-07-28 07:11:25.000 | Arthur |
| 2 | 2020-07-18 13:24:02.000 | 2020-07-18 13:38:42.000 | Arthur |
| 3 | 2020-07-03 09:27:03.000 | 2020-07-03 10:35:24.000 | Arthur |
| 4 | 2020-07-05 19:42:38.000 | 2020-07-05 20:07:52.000 | Bob |
| 5 | 2020-07-04 10:22:48.000 | 2020-07-04 10:24:32.000 | Bob |

Any ideas?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Does [Efficient date range overlap calculation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044084/efficient-date-range-overlap-calculation-in-python) answer your question? Or [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap), [Algorithm to detect overlapping periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods), [How to find rows with overlapping date ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288858/how-to-find-rows-with-overlapping-date-ranges)

Comment: More Pandas: [Efficiently finding overlap between many date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266424/efficiently-finding-overlap-between-many-date-ranges),

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked a similar question just yesterday so here it is:

```py
ends = df['starttime'].values < df['endtime'].values[:, None]
starts = df['starttime'].values > df['starttime'].values[:, None]
same_name = (df['Username'].values == df['Username'].values[:, None])

# check for rows where all three conditions are met
# count the nubmer of matches by sum across axis=1 !!!
df['overlap'] = (ends & starts & same_name).sum(1)

df
```

To answer your final question for the mean value you would then run:

```py
df['overlap'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Pandas groupby function as you suggested in your tag already, by username. Let me describe the general workflow below per grouped user:

- Collect all start times and stop times as 'moments of change in activities'.
- Loop over all of them in your grouped dataframe
- Use e.g. [Pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to check how many cases are 'active' at moments of changes.
- Save these in a list to compute the average count of cases

I don't have your code, but in pseudo-code it would look something like:

```
df = ...  # your raw df
grouped = df.groupby(by='Username')

for user, user_df in grouped:
    cases = []
    user_starts_cases = user_df['starttime'].to_numpy()
    user_stops_cases = user_df['stoptime'].to_numpy()
    times_of_activity_changes = np.concatenate(user_starts_cases, user_stops_cases)
    
    for xs in times_of_activity_changes:
        num_activities = len(user_df.loc[(user_df['starttime'] <= xs) & (user_df['stoptime'] >= xs)])  # mind the brackets
        active_cases.append(num_activities)
    
    print(sum(active_cases)/len(active_cases))
```

It depends a bit what you would call 'on average' but with this you could sample the amount of active cases at the times of your interest and compute an average.